# Trying to sort a text file with dates in brackets with "sort"

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, sh

I'm trying to sort a text by date.
My file format is:

```
...
[15/08/2019 - 01:58:49] some text here
[15/08/2019 - 02:21:23] more text here
[15/08/2019 - 02:56:11] blah blah blah
...
```

I've tried multiple different methods with the **sort** command.

One attempt: "**sort -b --key=1n --debug Final_out.txt**"

```
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields
sort: option '-b' is ignored

^ no match for key
^ no match for key
...
__
.?
^ no match for key
__
.?
^ no match for key
__
sort: write failed: 'standard output': Input/output error
sort: write error
```

Second attempt: "**sort -n -b --key=10,11 --debug Final_out.txt**"
Produced same output above

Just about to tear my hair out. This has to be possible, it's Linux! Come someone kindly give me pointers?

Comment: You're going to have to use awk or something to extract the timestamps, convert them to something that can be sorted lexicographically, and pass that on to sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Shawnn suggests, how about a bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

pat='^\[([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})[[:blank:]]+-[[:blank:]]+([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\]'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $pat ]]; then
        m=( "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}" )      # make a copy just to shorten the variable name
        echo -e "${m[3]}${m[2]}${m[1]}_${m[4]}\t$line"
    fi
done < file.txt | sort -t $'\t' -k1,1 | cut -f2-
```

- The variable `pat` is a regular expression to match the date and time field
  and assigns bash variable `BASH_REMATCH[@]` to day, month, year and time
  in order.
- After extracting the date and time field, it generates a new string
  composed of year, month, day and time in a sortable order and prepend
  the string to the current line delimited with a tab
- Then the whole lines are piped to `sort` keyed on the 1st field.
- Finally the 1st field is `cut` off.

The input file `file.txt`:

```
[10/01/2020 - 01:23:45] lorem ipsum
[15/08/2019 - 02:21:23] more text here
[15/08/2019 - 02:56:11] blah blah blah
[15/08/2019 - 01:58:49] some text here
[14/08/2019 - 12:34:56] dolor sit amet
```

Output:

```
[14/08/2019 - 12:34:56] dolor sit amet
[15/08/2019 - 01:58:49] some text here
[15/08/2019 - 02:21:23] more text here
[15/08/2019 - 02:56:11] blah blah blah
[10/01/2020 - 01:23:45] lorem ipsum
```

Comment: Maybe also link to [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Comment: @tripleee Yep. `Perl` can do it in a formulated way.

Comment: The language doesn't really matter; the general idea is to prefix your data with a normalized version, sort that, and then discard the normalized version.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative but shorter sorting way using `gnu awk`:

```
cat file
[10/01/2020 - 01:23:45] lorem ipsum
[15/08/2019 - 02:21:23] more text here
[15/08/2019 - 02:56:11] blah blah blah
[15/08/2019 - 01:58:49] some text here
[14/08/2019 - 12:34:56] dolor sit amet
```

Use this awk:

```sh
awk -v FPAT='[0-9:]+' '{ map[$3,$2,$1,$4] = $0 } 
END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; for (k in map) print map[k] }' file
```

```
[14/08/2019 - 12:34:56] dolor sit amet
[15/08/2019 - 01:58:49] some text here
[15/08/2019 - 02:21:23] more text here
[15/08/2019 - 02:56:11] blah blah blah
[10/01/2020 - 01:23:45] lorem ipsum
```

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue with my HISTORY with HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "

To sort according to year, month and day, I used this options in sort:

- before

```
history | awk '/0[78]\/06/{print" "$1"  "$2" "$3" command number "NR}'|head -20
 1921  07/06/22 09:21:05 command number 925
 1922  07/06/22 13:23:31 command number 926
 1923  07/06/22 13:24:16 command number 927
 1924  07/06/22 13:23:31 command number 928
 1925  07/06/22 13:24:16 command number 929
 1926  08/06/22 10:59:12 command number 930
 1927  08/06/22 10:59:21 command number 931
 1928  08/06/22 10:59:26 command number 932
 1929  08/06/22 10:59:27 command number 933
 1930  08/06/22 10:59:34 command number 934
 1931  08/06/22 10:59:44 command number 935
 1932  08/06/22 11:01:47 command number 936
 1933  08/06/22 11:03:35 command number 937
 1934  08/06/22 11:03:44 command number 938
 1935  08/06/22 11:03:48 command number 939
 1936  08/06/22 11:04:02 command number 940
 1937  08/06/22 11:12:17 command number 941
 1938  07/06/22 13:24:16 command number 942
 1939  08/06/22 09:22:10 command number 943
 1940  08/06/22 09:29:41 command number 944
```

- after

```
history | awk '/0[78]\/06/{print" "$1"  "$2" "$3" command number "NR}'|head -20|sort -bn -k2.7,2.8 -k2.4,2.5 -k2.1,2.2 -k3.1,3.2 -k3.4,3.5 -k3.7,3.8 -k1
 1921  07/06/22 09:21:05 command number 925
 1922  07/06/22 13:23:31 command number 926
 1924  07/06/22 13:23:31 command number 928
 1923  07/06/22 13:24:16 command number 927
 1925  07/06/22 13:24:16 command number 929
 1938  07/06/22 13:24:16 command number 942
 1939  08/06/22 09:22:10 command number 943
 1940  08/06/22 09:29:41 command number 944
 1926  08/06/22 10:59:12 command number 930
 1927  08/06/22 10:59:21 command number 931
 1928  08/06/22 10:59:26 command number 932
 1929  08/06/22 10:59:27 command number 933
 1930  08/06/22 10:59:34 command number 934
 1931  08/06/22 10:59:44 command number 935
 1932  08/06/22 11:01:47 command number 936
 1933  08/06/22 11:03:35 command number 937
 1934  08/06/22 11:03:44 command number 938
 1935  08/06/22 11:03:48 command number 939
 1936  08/06/22 11:04:02 command number 940
 1937  08/06/22 11:12:17 command number 941
```

Explainations in `sort -bn -k2.7,2.8 -k2.4,2.5 -k2.1,2.2 -k3.1,3.2 -k3.4,3.5 -k3.7,3.8 -k1` command :

- d is for remove leading blanks
- n is for numeric
- k2.7,2.8 is for 2nd key (the date) from 7th to 8th char (yy)
- etc for keys 2 and 3 (the time)

And, for @Ventus, the solution can be `sort -n -k1.9,1.12 -k1.5,1.6 -k1.2,1.3 -k3.1,3.2 -k3.4,3.5 -k3.7,3.8`